# C#: How can I create property (read-only) that shows hours

Tags: c#, constructor

I have a struct with constructors:

```
public struct Time
{
    public Time(int minutes)
        : this()
    {
        this.Minutes = minutes;
    }

    public Time(int hours, int minutes)
        : this(minutes)
    {
        this.Hours = hours;
    }
```

I need help to create a property (read-only) which will allow me to indicate hours in 24 hour format ( 00.XX - 23.XX ). As I indicated above, I supply property's value by calling a constructor. My current incomplete attempt:

```
public readonly int Hours { get; }
```

Happy to hear any suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: Why aren't you using `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not  allowed to use TimeSpan. It is an assignment.

Comment: You can provide a block for your `get { return something; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
public struct Time
{
    public Time(int minutes)
        : this()
    {
        this.Minutes = minutes;
    }

    public Time(int hours, int minutes)
        : this(minutes)
    {
        this.Hours = hours%23;
    }

    public int Hours {get;set;}
    public int Minutes {get;set;}

    public string To24Hours{get {
        return $"{this.Hours} : {this.Minutes}";
    }}
}
```

This requires though that you ensure the hours you put in your constructor is already in 24 hours format.

Comment: Could you tell me why one i can ensure that?

Comment: depends on your input source...where are you getting the hours from ? In other words, are you displaying the current time or your problem involves receiving a time value then converting to 21 hours

Comment: for Hours output should look something like this
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
23 -> 23
24 -> 0
25 -> 1
so if for example input is 26 outpout should be 2 . I need to apply this logic in constructor somehow. Maybe using % operator. 25 % 24 = 1

Comment: From your explanation then it seems you will have already sorted the processing for the Hours using the % operator before you pass it to constructor or you can do the manipulation at the constructor level

Comment: Can you give me a hint how can i do that at the constructor level?

Comment: Check the edited code, on the constructor hours%23, this will ensure the value is converted to 24 hours system and nothing overflows